# React-Router useHistory() in nested functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've run into an issue getting the `useHistory()` hook to work in my app.  It's working in the top level children of `<Route>`, but in any component included in that top level child it doesn't work.

Better explained with the code.

In a Frame container:

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

<Switch>
   <Route path={`${path}/reading`} exact>
     <Reading />
   </Route>
</Switch>
```

In the `Reading` component:

```
export default function Reading(props) {

   const history = useHistory();
   // history is correct here and contains the pop(), push(), etc.

   return (
      <>
         <Navbar />
      </>
  );
```

}

In the `Navbar` component:

```
export default function Navbar(props) {

    let history = useHistory();
    // history is undefined here - WHY??

    return (
       // navbar JSX code here
    );
```

}

Why doesn't `useHistory()` work in the `Navbar` component?  It doesn't seem correct to me that only top level children can use that hook, it should be accessible down the chain, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, hopefully this helps someone else.  My project uses an /app folder and also a /common folder for things, each with their own package.json file.  The Navbar was in the /common and the other files were in /app.

What react-router-dom does is store the history information in its own file in the /node_modules folder, and not anywhere within your React app.  So, since I had two package.json files, I had two /node_modules folders, and therefore the Navbar was looking for a history that didn't exist, because it was in the other /node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

`useHistory` does not work in the component which are not inside the `Route`. So use `withRouter` in the navbar component.

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";


const Navbar=(props)=> {

    let history = useHistory();
    // history is undefined here - WHY??

    return (
       // navbar JSX code here
    );
}


export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  It says you can't use withRouter() outside a Route